# css relative alignment upon image

Tags: css, css-position

I am trying to align a div on top of my image. Horizontal alignment works fine, vertical offset however doesn't. Also, the background-color of `#studentenlijn` is not applied.

HTML Snippet:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="studentenlijn">STUDENTENLIJN</div>
    <img src="http://lsvb.nl/s/lsvbheader.jpg" class="banner" />
</div>
```

Relevant CSS

```
#studentenlijn {
    width: 10%;
    height: 10%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 30%;
    left: 72%;
    background-color: #660000;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YGeLA/

Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry! I tried so, but it looked messed up. Will try again!

Comment: The background color isn't working because the `height` and `width` are `0`. They are set in `%`, and the parent is set in `%`. The `body` and `html` don't have a set `height` and `width` though, so the `%` isn't doing anything.

Comment: @Doran Either add a padding to `#studentenlijn` or set the height&width as px/em to resolve the bg color issue.

Comment: In the future, it would be helpful if you'd post a screenshot or sketch of what you want things to look like, because at the moment we aren't really sure. Fix some things messes up others, and without knowing what the box is supposed to be, we can't really fix things entirely, we can just diagnose general issues.

Answer (score 0):

Your body had a height of 0, thus affecting the height of the containers within it when you try to specify a percentage height. Another problem was that you had a floating image within your container div, and thus you need to hide the overflow in order for the container to properly calculate the heights of elements within.

I have made some minor changes to your fiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/YGeLA/1/

I added:

- `height: 100%;` to the `body` element
- `overflow: hidden;` to `#container` which forces the container to respect the height of all elements within it.

Comment: Great! Thank you all! Adding a padding and overflow fixed it

Answer (score 0):

The size of your div is:

```
#studentenlijn {
width: 10%;
height: 10%;
}
```

So it'll be a % of the parent element. The parent element, your container, is:

```
#container {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
```

At this point, your browser can't determine which size should have your block.
So you won't be able to center it (Since you can't center an element which have not a browser-determined size).
You can't see the background-color for the same reason. It is applied, but you won't see your colored block because his size is 0.

Try to solve it, and it would be easier to center your div. In case it doesn't help you, edit your post with your modification :)

Comment: The reason it can't is because `html` and `body` don't have sizes. If they were added, then setting everything to `%` would work just fine.

Comment: Any parent element must have a specified size to use % on child elements. So in fact, you're right :) That what my post means, maybe isn't clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

the container height is 0px. so you can't give height 100%

you have to set height in px

look at this update

```
        #container {
        position:relative;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        line-height: 0;
    }
    .banner {
        width:100%;
    }
    #studentenlijn {
        width:200px;
        height:30px;
        position:absolute;
        top:35px;
        left:72%;
        background-color:#660000;
line-height:30px
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YGeLA/2/